# Sharepoint 2010. How do I lock item in list when user edits it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list view on a page that has several items. This view is accessible to several users. I'm warned if several users start to edit the same item simultaneously. Is it possible to lock item when any user starts to edit it? Second user should get a message like "The item is being edited by another user" or something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint has own locking mechanism [Checkout](http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/help/home?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=SPOSTANDARD&helpID=RequireCheckout&ver=16&services=OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,MCOSTANDARD,EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE,SHAREPOINTWAC_DEVELOPER,SHAREPOINT_S_DEVELOPER)

Checking out files prevents people from editing files simultaneously and lets people add check-in comments to clarify version history when versioning is turned on for the library
[image]